# Unknown method in Visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, visualforce-component

I am creating a self registration form using visualforce for community portal users.When user try to signup with details the details should match the contact details.

Controller

```
public class testselfregistration 
{
   public string email {get;set;}
   public string consumer {get;set;}
    public string firstname {get;set;}
  public string lastname {get;set;}
    public string phone {get;set;}
   
    public  void createuser(string email,string consumer,string firstname,string lastname,string phone)
    {
        list< contact> c=[select Consumer_Number__c,Email from contact where Email=:email and  Consumer_Number__c=:consumer
                         and firstname=:firstname and lastname=:lastname and Phone=:phone ];
                User userExample = new User();       
                Account portalAccount1 = new Account(
                Name = 'TestAccount');
                insert portalAccount1;

                Contact contact1 = new Contact(
                FirstName = 'Test',
                Lastname = 'McTesty', 
                AccountId = portalAccount1.Id,
                Email = 'test@test.com');
                insert contact1;
        
          Profile systemAdminProfileId = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'community practice'];
                userExample.Username = 'firstname';
                userExample.FirstName = 'firstname';
                userExample.LastName = 'lastname';
                userExample.Alias = 'Alias';
                userExample.Email = 'email';
                userExample.TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/New_York';
                userExample.LocaleSidKey = 'en_US';
                userExample.EmailEncodingKey = 'ISO-8859-1';
                userExample.ProfileId = systemAdminProfileId.id;
                userExample.ContactId = contact1.Id;
                userExample.LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US';
         
                for(contact cc:c)
                {
                    if(cc.Consumer_Number__c == consumer &&  cc.Email==email )
                    {
                        insert userExample;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        CC.addError('YOU CANNOT CREATE A USER WITHOUT A MATCHING CONTACT');
                    }
                       
                    
                }
        }
}
```

visualforce

```
<apex:page controller="testselfregistration" showHeader="false">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageblock title="ENTER THE SELF REGISTRATION FORM DETAILS">
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
                <apex:commandButton action="{!createuser}" value="Signup"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageblocksection columns="1">
               

                <apex:pageblocksectionitem>
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Enter firstname" />
                    <apex:inputText value="{!email}" />
                             </apex:pageblocksectionitem>
                 <apex:pageblocksectionitem>
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Enter lastname" />
                    <apex:inputText value="{!lastname}" />
                             </apex:pageblocksectionitem>
                 <apex:pageblocksectionitem>
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Enter lastname" />
                    <apex:inputText value="{!lastname}" />
                             </apex:pageblocksectionitem>
                 <apex:pageblocksectionitem>
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Enter consumer" />
                    <apex:inputText value="{!consumer}" />
                             </apex:pageblocksectionitem>
                  <apex:pageblocksectionitem>
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Enter phone" />
                    <apex:inputText value="{!phone}" />
                             </apex:pageblocksectionitem>
                     </apex:pageblocksection>
            </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
public void createuser(string email,string consumer,string firstname,string lastname,string phone) {
```

To just:

```
public void createuser() {
```

Because the class variables (e.g. `email`) are bound to input fields (e.g. `<apex:inputText value="{!email}" />`), those values are automatically provided to the `createuser` method without needing to specify any parameters.

You've also accidentally discovered [Name Shadowing](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_name_shadowing.htm). Naming a method parameter the same as a class parameter "shadows" the outer variable. That means you'd have to use `this` to access the class level variable, which isn't what we want here.

Answer (score 0):

It detects the method as unknown since there is no method declared by that name that doesn't require parameters, your method needs to receive its parameters declared in the function.
Some links that explain how to do so:
http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.com/2011/07/passing-parameters-to-apex-method-from.html

https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/application-development/9781782170808/1/ch01lvl1sec13/passing-parameters-to-action-methods